# Как правильно перевести секунды в формат HH:mm:ss?

Tags: java

Получаю продолжительность видео с ВК в секундах. Никак не могу перевести их в формат HH:mm:ss

Вот мой метод

```
public String secToStr(int duration){
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
    String time = df.format(new Date(duration));
    return time;
}
```

Любой `duration` переводится в 3 часа. Что я делаю не так? Как можно это сделать двумя-тремя строчками?

Comment: Это дата, указание на конкретную отметку времени. Когда вы создаете ее таким образом, она принимает на вход количество миллисекунд, а не что-то другое.

Comment: На всякий случай замечу (к вопросу в общем-то не относится), что не стоит путать `HH` и `hh`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Разобрался. Вот так надо

```
public String secToStr(int duration){
    return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", duration / 3600, duration / 60 % 60, duration % 60);
}
```

Comment: Добавлю. Достоинством подобного варианта является также тот факт, что он корректно обрабатывает интервалы более суток, в отличии от трюка с Date.

Comment: добавлю свои пять копеек, конструкция TimeUnit.SECONDS.to* повысит читабельность данного варианта

Comment: @PavelMayorov можно Duration использовать и либу  http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.0/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DurationFormatUtils.html

Answer (score 3):

Конструктор `java.util.Date(long)` принимает миллисекунды.
[Источник](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date-long-)

```
public static String secToStr(int duration){
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
    String time = df.format(new Date(duration*1000)); // Миллисекунды
    return time;
}
```